# Visual Studio 2010 のオーバーライドのインテリセンスが効かなくなった

Tags: visual-studio

Visual Studio 2010を使っています。ReSharperをインストール後、ほとんどのインテリセンスは問題なく自動表示されますが、オーバーライドのメソッドだけ自動表示されないです。

例えば、親クラスで「protected internal virtual void OnUpdate()」を定義されていて、子クラスで「protected override void」を入力し、スペースを入力しても、オーバーライドできるメソッドの候補一覧が表示してくれません。ReSharperをインストールされていない別のPCで試したところ、オーバーライドできるメソッドの候補一覧が問題なく表示されます。

これはどこかの設定いじれば直ることでしょうか。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: ビルドし直したら、うまく表示されるかもしれません
試してみてください

Comment: 稀にIntelliSenseデータベースが破損するケースがあります。一度SDFファイルを削除（or 退避）してみても良いかもしれません。同ファイルは自動再生成されます。

Answer (score 1):

直接の回答になるかわかりませんが、私の場合、アクセス修飾子protectedも戻り値voidも入力せず「ov」辺りまで入力します。すると補完候補に「override」が出てきますのでスペースキーを押すと今度はオーバーライドメソッドの候補が出てきます。

これはReSharperの機能ではなくVisual Studio側の機能です。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。これも一つの対処手段ですね。

いろいろ試してみたら、ＲｅＳｈａｒｐｅｒのバージョンとの相性問題のようです。最新バージョンの9.1はそういった問題がありましたが、8.2.3で試してみたところ、問題なくインテリセンスが動作しました。